# SQL: Limit on CASE (number of WHEN, THEN conditions)

Tags: sql, mysql, oracle

Consider the query (it runs on both Oracle and MySQL)

```
UPDATE table1
SET something_id = CASE 
  WHEN table1_id = 1446 THEN 423 
  WHEN table1_id = 2372 THEN 426 
  WHEN table1_id = 2402 THEN 428 
  WHEN table1_id = 2637 THEN 429 
  WHEN table1_id = 2859 THEN 430 
  WHEN table1_id = 3659 THEN 433 
END 
WHERE table1_id IN (1446,2372,2402,2637,2859,3659)
```

This query can get quite large, so I was wondering what is the limit on the number of conditions (WHEN, THEN statements) a single query can hold. Is there a way around it?

**For example:**
I know that the max number of values that can be passed to `IN` is 1000 and to overcome this we can do

```
`WHERE TABLE1_ID IN ([1000 values]) OR TABLE1_ID IN ([more values])`
```

Comment: The WHERE clause is unnecessary - you're already filtering by table1_id in the CASE statement.

Comment: The WHERE clause is absolutely necessary.  Without it, you'd update every row in the table and those TABLE1_ID rows not specifically mentioned in the CASE statement would be set to NULL.  At least, that's the behavior you'd get in Oracle-- I can't imagine that MySQL is different in that respect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The docs for [10gR2](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm#i1033392) say:

> The maximum number of arguments in a
>   CASE expression is 255. All
>   expressions count toward this limit,
>   including the initial expression of a
>   simple CASE expression and the
>   optional ELSE expression. Each WHEN
>   ... THEN pair counts as two arguments.
>   To avoid exceeding this limit, you can
>   nest CASE expressions so that the
>   return_expr itself is a CASE
>   expression.

Answer (score 12):

Put your correspondences into a helper table:

```
id   value

1446  423
2372  426 
…
```

and join.

In `Oracle`:

```
UPDATE  (
        SELECT  something_id, value
        FROM    table1
        JOIN    helper
        ON      table1.table1_id = helper.id
        )
SET     something_id = value
```

(don't forget to make `helper.id` a `PRIMARY KEY` for this to work)

In `MySQL`:

```
UPDATE  table1
JOIN    helper
ON      table1.table1 = helper.id
SET     table1.something_id = value
```

Comment: You beat me by 26 seconds... Sometimes I wonder how you do that.

Comment: @Quassnoi: NOT INSERT CURSOR EXECUTE!

Comment: @Quassnoi: I have it bound so that I can quickly say "NOT CURSOR! NOT CURSOR!"

Answer (score 7):

If you have a lot of case statements like this, you should move them into a table to simplify things:

```
NewTable
table1_id  | result
-----------+---------
1446       | 423
2372       | 426
...        | ...
```

Then join on it in your query:

```
UPDATE table1
SET something_id = NewTable.result
INNER JOIN NewTable
ON table1.table1_id = NewTable.table1_id
```

It's a lot simpler.

Comment: Nice as it might be, I don't think this UPDATE syntax works in Oracle.

Answer (score 4):

In MySQL you are limited solely by the byte size of the query. This is controlled by the "max_allowed_packet" setting for your server. I cannot speak for Oracle.