# How many WHEN....THEN Condition is allow in CASE in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, case, decode

I am working with the CASE & DECODE. 
The SYNTAX of CASE is :

```
CASE  [ expression ]
  WHEN condition_1 THEN result_1
  WHEN condition_2 THEN result_2
  ...
  WHEN condition_n THEN result_n
  ELSE result
END
```

In CASE  if we write any condition we can write it by using WHEN...THEN.

SO, Could you tell me how many number of times we can write WHEN... THEN condition  in one CASE.
is their any limit to write WHEN....THEN Condition in one CASE.

Thanks for your reply.
Actually I got the answer of my question.
I got the answer of My question.

Actually we can write only 255 comparisons in one CASE.
Each  WHEN...THEN  clause is considered 2 comparisons.

we can write 255 comparisons in one CASE statement.
Each WHEN...THEN clause is considered 2 comparisons.

SAME LIMIT IS APPLIED TO DECODE.

The maximum number of arguments in DECODE  function is 255.
This includes  :
EXPRESSION,SEARCH and RESULT arguments.

Comment: This question was asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1160459/1359231

Comment: @joshp: your linked question deals with MySQL, this one is for Oracle.

Answer (score 7):

Right from the 11.2 manual at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions004.htm#SQLRF20037

> ***The maximum number of arguments in a CASE expression is 65535**. All expressions count toward this limit, including the initial expression of a simple CASE expression and the optional ELSE expression. Each WHEN ... THEN pair counts as two arguments. To avoid exceeding this limit, you can nest CASE expressions so that the return_expr itself is a CASE expression*

(Emphasis mine)

**Edit**
Apparently this limit has been significantly increased in 11.2 because in the 11.1 and the 10.2 manual the limit is documented as 255

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm#i1033392
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/expressions004.htm#i1033392

Comment: You might like to add that in 10.2 the documented limit is 255: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm

Answer (score -1):

There is no limit on this, you can do as much as you want...
but what is your goal / approach? I think you should solve such a big case when issue with a model.

Comment: Do you have a source for this answer? Previous answers suggest a limit. Don't know who is right. Of course I believe there will be a practical limit regardless of what docs say.

Comment: Well the limit are your resources of course. But there is no general limit how man WHEN blocks you can add. I searched MSN Tech Net and didn't find any limit hint so far.

Comment: @YvesR: why did you search MSN when this question is marked as Oracle?